# Is a for...of loop the same as this regular loop?

Tags: javascript

`a = [1, 2];`

Is `for (item of a) {}` similar to this `for` loop:

```js
for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    let item = a[index]
}
```

I've noticed you can use `continue` & `break` in `for...of` too.

I think I prefer using a regular `for` loop - feels like I have more control.

Comment: [`for .. of` invokes a custom iterator hook](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) so... not exactly the same.

Comment: No it's not the same. It uses a different mechanism to iterate, calling `a[Symbol.Iterator]`, and that is a very different mechanism. For example, iterators are not accessed by index and therefore do not have to be of a known size or even finite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's functionally the same, assuming `a` is a standard array.

> I think I prefer using a regular `for` loop - feels like I have more control.

You'll stop feeling that way after writing your 100th `for` loop, realizing you only needed the extra control in 1% of those cases, and you had unnecessary verbosity in 99% and weird bugs in 10% of them.

`Array#forEach` is another good choice. And often, what you really want is `Array#map` (if you want to transform each item of the array in some way).

Answer (score 0):

`for` is for objects have [] operator. `for..of` is for iterable objects. Some objects can iterable and  have [] operator like Arrays.

```js
let myIterable = {};
myIterable[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
};
for(x of myIterable) {
  console.log(x)
}
```